# Creating a multi dimensional array - is there a better way than this

Tags: php

I have this code

```
        foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

            $output[] = array();

            //adding a blank array to the end doesn't seem to 
            //advance the array pointer so do it manually.
            $test = end($output); 

            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                //specifically this bit
                $output[key($output)][] = $cell->getValue();
            }
        }
```

But I don't like how I've found the current key using

```
$output[key($output)][] = $cell->getValue();
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use another variable?

```
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cells = array();
    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
        $cells[] = $cell->getValue();
    }
    $output[] = $cells;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> adding a blank array to the end doesn't seem to advance the array pointer so do it manually

This is correct, but the array pointer position should have no bearing on what you are doing here.

You should build the new sub array on it's own, then append the completed array to the `$output` at the end:

```
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

  $temp = array();

  foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
    $temp[] = $cell->getValue();
  }

  $output[] = $temp;

}
```

Comment: yeah - it's got nothing to do with the question. but indicated I was doing it wrong - your answer is what I was missing. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array, fill this array with your data and add your newly created array to $output at the end of your loop.

Comment: Ah there was someone faster :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $i => $row) {

    $output[$i] = array();

    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
        $output[$i][] = $cell->getValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cells = array();
    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
        array_push($cells, $cell->getValue());
    }
    array_push($output, $cells);
}
```